# CSS- Float not working as it's supposed to

Tags: html, css, css-float

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: arial;
   line-height: 16px;
 }
 #topbar {
   background-color: #600c0c;
   width: 100%;
   height: 46px;
   color: white;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .fixedwidth {
   width: 1050px;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #logodiv {
   padding-top: 5px;
   float: left;
   border-right: 1px solid #b20505;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
 }
 #signindiv {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   border-right: 1px solid #b20505;
   padding: 1px 80px 0px 12px;
   float: left;
 }
 #topmenudiv {
   float: left;
 }
 #topmenudiv ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0px;
 }
 #topmenudiv li {
   list-style: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   border-right: 1px solid #b20505;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
   float: left;
 }
 #searchdiv {
   float: left;
   padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
 }
 #searchdiv input {
   height: 25px;
   border: none;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   padding-left: 10px;
   background-image: url(images/Search.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: right center;
 }
 .break {
   clear: both;
 }
 #newsbar {
   background-color: #b20505;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   color: white;
   margin: 0;
 }
 #newsbar p {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   padding-top: 30px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   float: left;
 }
 #newsheader {
   font-size: 3em;
 }
 #uk {
   font-size: 0.7em;
   padding-left: 8px;
 }
 rss {
   float: right;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My BBC</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="topbar">
      <div class="fixedwidth">
        <div id="logodiv">
          <img src="images/BBCLogo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="signindiv">
          <p>Sign In</p>
        </div>
        <div id="topmenudiv">
          <ul>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Sport</li>
            <li>Weather</li>
            <li>iPlayer</li>
            <li>TV</li>
            <li>Radio</li>
            <li>More...</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="searchdiv">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div id="newsbar">
      <div class="fixedwidth">
        <p id="newsheader">NEWS <span id="uk">UK</span>
        </p>
        <div id="rss">
          RSS
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to emulate the  [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/) news website, my problem is the word "RSS" is supposed to be floating right, but it doesn't despite that i already assigned width to the whole container div. I don't understand.
[Here is how it looks..](http://jsbin.com/howelowiwu/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Your CSS rule is `rss {...` and it should be `#rss {...`. Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Comment: Why do i feel stupid ?! -_-*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for the previous answer ! 
Actuall you are missing "#" in the style sheet. 
it should be

```
  #rss {
   float: right;
 }
```

There is only rss is there . Just add "#" before RSS. then it will work

Comment: I've already noted this in the comment. Please don't try and farm rep from a question where the mistake is due to a typo as it has no value. Instead, vote to close it as off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

If this ok you can use like this..

```
<div class="fixedwidth">
      <div id="rss">
          RSS
        </div>
        <p id="newsheader">NEWS <span id="uk">UK</span>
        </p>

      </div>
```

Just use #rss content above the #newsheader content
.

Comment: Opps that answer is for RSS to float at left ..